# loop an array from a html rendered page using python

Tags: python

I am scraping on python data from a rendered web page using requests html. My code works fine to show just one result, but I'd like to loop it to get all data.

This is my code:

```
import requests_html

matchlink = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/football/germany/3-liga/results/'

from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get(matchlink)
r.html.render(timeout=20)


allmatch = r.html.find('.in-match')

match = allmatch[0].text
        
print(match)
```

I am a newbie of python, I thought to use a loop FOR but I don't know exactly how to set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `for` loop to iterate over the `allmatch` list!

```
import requests_html

matchlink = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/football/germany/3-liga/results/'

from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get(matchlink)
r.html.render(timeout=20)

allmatch = r.html.find('.in-match')

for match in allmatch:
    print(match.text)
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this

```py
allmatch = r.html.find('.in-match')

for match in allmatch:
    print(match.text)
```

Comment: Yes, it works! thanks!